# How to remove TapGestureRecognizer on a grid in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.forms

I have the following code in Xamarin forms:

```
switch mode
{
   case 1:
   {
      wordGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
      {
         NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
         Command = new Command(() =>
         {
            abc();

         }),
      });   
      break;            
   }
   case 2:
   {
      if(start) 
      {
         Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
         {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
               abc();
            });
         return false;
         });
     }
     break;
   }
}
```

My application uses either tap event (mode==1) or timer (mode==2) to call abc(). The mode value is controlled by me going to a settings screen and changing it.

After I switch from tap setting to timer setting and back a few times when on a timer setting, abc() runs every 5 seconds but I can still tap on the grid (which will then perform the function for that tap event).

How can I remove this tap event (on the grid) when Im on a timer setting?

Comment: Why don't you just create a global boolean which can track if the user tapped already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in case 2:

```
  case 2:
  {
     if(start) 
     {
       wordGrid.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
       ...
     }
     break;
  }
```